# Not getting input inside td with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, html-table

I have a problem not getting the `<input>` inside a specified `<td>`. Through jQuery, I want once an "input search" entered, get just those `<tr>` that have these entries.Then when the input is empty return all the entries.

Here is my code :

```
<table id="hosts">
    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="host"><input type="text" id="inputhost" value="214215" size="16"></td>
        <td id="rand"><input type="text" id="inputrand" value="442" size="16"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="host"><input type="text" id="inputhost" value="1252512" size="16"></td>
        <td id="rand"><input type="text" id="inputrand" value="556" size="16"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="host"><input type="text" id="inputhost" value="2114" size="16"></td>
        <td id="rand"><input type="text" id="inputrand" value="4666" size="16"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="host"><input type="text" id="inputhost" value="3245466" size="16"></td>
        <td id="rand"><input type="text" id="inputrand" value="22654" size="16"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="host"><input type="text" id="inputhost" value="24588" size="16"></td>
        <td id="rand"><input type="text" id="inputrand" value="54877" size="16"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

and this is my jQuery code:

```
function removeHighlighting(highlightedElements) {
    highlightedElements.each(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        element.replaceWith(element.html());
    })
}

function addHighlighting(element, textToHighlight) {
    var text = element.text();
    var highlightedText = '<em>' + textToHighlight + '</em>';
    var newText = text.replace(textToHighlight, highlightedText);

    element.html(newText);
}

$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    removeHighlighting($("table tr em"));

    $("#hosts tr").each(function (index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);

            var $host = $row.find("#host input#inputhost");
            var $dest = $row.find("#rand input#inputrand");
            var host_id = $host.text();
            var dest_id = $dest.text();
            var hostIndex = host_id.indexOf(value);
            var destIndex = dest_id.indexOf(value);
            if ((hostIndex == -1) && (destIndex == -1)) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else if ((hostIndex != -1) && (destIndex != -1)) {
                addHighlighting($host, value);
                addHighlighting($dest, value);
                $row.show();
            }
            else if (hostIndex != -1) {
                addHighlighting($host, value);
                $row.show();
            }
            else {
                addHighlighting($dest, value);
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate IDs! You don't really need them; remove them and then your code will be:

```
        var $host = $row.find("td:first input");
        var $dest = $row.find("td:eq(1) input");
```

**UPDATE**

You also have to update your code to:

```
        var host_id = $host.val();
        var dest_id = $dest.val();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Pw4P2/)

Comment: Hi! I have tried this for all entries, with your proposed find, but in vain !!   
    <table id="hosts">
    <tr><th>First</th><th>Second</th></tr>
    <tr><td>
                 <input type="text" id="inputhost" value="214215" size="16">
    </td><td>
                         <input type="text" id="inputrand" value="442" size="16">
        </td></tr>

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle that shows the updated code and we'll take it from there. You still have the same `id's` in your markup though. However, with the code above it shouldn't matter as it does not use them anyway.

Comment: Thank's that's exactly what I want with some modifications !! It works pretty well now !

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you. Feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cant give `Id` like that. Id should be unique. change them to class. then it will work. Then your selector will be

```
$(this).find(".host input.inputhost")
```

Comment: I have changed lines to : <tr><td Id="host">
                         <input type="text" Id="inputhost" value="24588" size="16">
        </td><td Id="rand">
                         <input type="text" Id="inputrand" value="54877" size="16">
        </td></tr> But still doesn't word. I also changed the find argument